# Rails not setting Sauce Lab session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, saucelabs

I am trying to run a sauce labs test, but Rails is not setting the session. My code to set the session in cucumber is as follows.

```
Before('@tag_thing') do
 data = { (Some hashes go here)}

 u = User.find_or_create_by(uuid: "thing") do |user|
 user.form_data = {Form::thing => data}
 user.draft_id = 42
 end
 page.set_rack_session(n400_user_data_uuid: u.draft_id)
 page.set_rack_session(uuid: "thing")
```

end